# Internet Access What is best, to use 4G USB sim card dongle in to Router or Use Router with Built in sim card 4G holder

Tags: wifi

I have searched a lot this couple of days and cant find the answer for the title

I have a USB dongle now but get very bad receiving
will it get better if i use a router where there is a built in Sim card holder. 
And if so why?
PS: I get the same bad result for testing the internet connection if i do the test on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

If router has better signal sensitivity than the USB dongle you use, you would get higher throughput. In most case routers outperforms USB dongles.